# How to make one time popup in all HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4-5 HTML pages, I want to display a popup only for one time, It means popup should be display in each page. It is working fine.

However I want, when hiding a modal using the close icon, that it will be never be displayed before close window tab.

```js
$(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown') {
        $("#popup").fadeIn();
        localStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown');
    }

    $('#popup-close').click(function (e) {
        $('#popup').fadeOut();
        localStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="footer-alert" id="popup" style="display:none;">
  <div class="footer-alert-close" id="popup-close">X</div>
  <p>We use cookies to make interactions with our websites and services easier and more meaningful, including learning to understand how they are used. You can read more about our <a href="privacy.html"><b>Privacy &amp; Cookies Policy here</b></a>. By continuing
    to use this site you are giving us your consent to our policy.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use localStorage or a cookie instead of sessionStorage.

Comment: i need to expire session after close window tab, i think there is sessionStorage working well.

Comment: Using sessionStorage is at odds with your question, then. If you want the popup state to be saved after the window closes, then you *have* to use a storage medium with a longer lifecycle than the session. There are no workarounds for that.

Comment: AFAIK the "EU Cookie Law" only requires you to show a usage information bar on first visit of a given user. Therefor I would absolutely agree with Rory that `LocalStorage` would be the correct storage area rather than `SessionStorage`.

Comment: i modified question as per LocalStorage but this is also not working, now popup is closing when i refresh page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove `localStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown');` from `if (localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown')` because it's set `your local storage` all time on page load in

> do this

```
    $(function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown') {
            $("#popup").fadeIn();
        }

        $('#popup-close').click(function (e) {
            $('#popup').fadeOut();
            localStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your issue is that you want to show the popup on all the pages until is closed. Once the user closes it, you don't want to show it again ever for same session.

You will need to remove these two lines as they will reset the session storage  every time on new html page prompting the popup even if it has been closed once):-

```
 sessionStorage.removeItem('shown');
 sessionStorage.clear();
```

you may even try localstorage or a cookie as per your need.

Comment: I can't remove these two lines because when user go to another page then i have to clear session for open modal on current page.

Comment: The above lines will clear sessionStorage and the user will get popup on each of your html page even though he has closed the popup in any one of them. The sessionstorage gets cleared out by default once the browser window is closed. You don't need to manually clear it.

Comment: i modified my code in my question but now popup is closing when i refresh page